# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO TransactionPurchase (
    PurID,
    AccCode,
    Credit,
    Debit,
    PrevBalance
)
VALUES (
    @PurID,
    @AccCode,
    @Credit,
    @Debit,
    (SELECT Balance FROM Accounts WHERE AccountCode IN (SELECT AccountCode FROM Accounts WHERE AccountCode = @AccCode))
    --(dbo.TotalCompanyBalance(@AccCode))
)
DECLARE @TranID bigint, @currBalance money
SET @TranID = (SELECT TOP 1 TranID FROM TransactionPurchase ORDER BY TranID DESC)
SET @currBalance = dbo.Debit(@AccCode)
UPDATE TransactionPurchase SET CurrentBalance = @currBalance WHERE TranID = @TranID
UPDATE Accounts SET Balance = @currBalance WHERE AccountCode = @AccCode
END
```

What is the problem here, I don't see any subquery that returns more than 1 value or am I missing something?

Comment: check this line ``SELECT Balance FROM Accounts WHERE AccountCode IN (SELECT AccountCode FROM Accounts WHERE AccountCode = @AccCode)`` and use ``TOP 1`` if needed

Comment: Why wouldn't you just write that as `SELECT Balance FROM Accounts WHERE AccountCode = @AccCode` anyway?

Comment: Just added a `TOP ` without an `ORDER BY` is going to return any arbitrary row, and lead to inconsistent results, @SaeedEsmaeelinejad .

Comment: @Larnu where cluase is important when condition was match then any record would be acceptable but I know order by is good for choose the best one if needed.

Comment: In this case we can see that all the rows are going to have the same value anyway. TBH I would be surprised if that returns more than one row as presumably AccountCode is unique in Accounts.The issue may also be inside a trigger fired by one of the data modification statements shown